# Core Plot animation with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer, core-plot

i am trying to animate Core Plot graph with NSTimer

```
- (void) animate
{
CGPoint *moved = [array objectAtIndex:0];

for (float i = 1.43; i<=2.91; i+=0.01) 
{
    moved.x = i;
    moved.y = i;

    if (timer != nil)
        [timer invalidate];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(reloadPlotData) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];  
    }

}

-(void) reloadPlotData
{
    [graph reloadData];
}
```

but there are not animation. data reloads only at the endpoint of loop

i'm tried also with [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1], but there are the same problem

how i can to fix it?

sorry for bad english.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how you're using the `moved` (`CGPoint` is a struct, not an object). That's not what your question was about, though.

You are resetting the timer every time through that loop, long before it gets a chance to fire. If you want the graph to update every second, get rid of the loop in `-animate`, create a repeating timer, increment the counter in `-reloadPlotData`, and stop the timer when you get to the last value (e.g., 2.91 from your example). You'll obviously need to store the counter in an instance variable or some other scope that will persist between calls to `-reloadPlotData`.

For example (untested):

@interface

```
myPoint *moved; // custom class with x and y properties
NSTimer *timer;
```

@implementation

```
- (void) animate
{
    moved = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    float start = 1.43;

    moved.x = start;
    moved.y = start;

    if (timer != nil)
        [timer invalidate];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(reloadPlotData)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];  
}

-(void) reloadPlotData
{
    moved = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    moved.x += 0.01f;
    moved.y += 0.01f;

    if ( moved.x > 2.91 ) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
    else {
        [graph reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: CGPoint is for example. instead of it i use own object, with x and y parameters

Comment: and i very new to objective-c and iOS coding.. can you give an example how to do it?